# Orientdb as a document-graph database

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb, document-database

I am using Neo4j and trying to find out the advantages of Orient as document-graph db over Neo4j.

How does it work in Orientdb to have features of a document database in a graphbdb? is the database in both mode (graph and document) using the same datasource? if so, then is it possible to edit data in documentdb and show it as a graphdb?

I worked with Orientdb and it seems that you can have your database either as graphdb or as documentdb, so I don't get the point of having both databases features in one db. I mean you can choose to have a pure documentdb or pure graphdb, but can't be some mixture of both, so it can be a graphdb like Neo4j or a documentdb like Mongodb. I need to know if I'm right or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you work with OrientDB Graph API, you can always accessing to the underlying Document Database API, so you can mix usage of both. For example you can embed a document inside a Vertex...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Luca, I wonder then if it's possible to import a graph database into document database, to be able to interact with it as a documentdb?

Comment: If you import a graph database in OrientDB you can access to it using the Document API from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

The difference between document and graph is just a matter of modelling relation ships. Here you can see a detailed [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/lvca/orientdb-document-or-graph-select-the-right-model). In short: if you use the document model you have direct relations between documents (vertexes), This means you can not store properties on the edge. If you use the graph model your relationships between documents (vertex) are going over a third edge-document where you store your edge-properties on. For me the big benefit of OrientDB is its ability to model documents using inheritance (for vertex and edges as well).

Comment: The presentation you mention is pretty old and no more valid. Look rather this : Graph or Document API? (http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Choosing-between-Graph-or-Document-API.html)